# StringBuilder loop: Local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, compiler-errors, initialization, stringbuilder

I have the following method that normalises a given XML tag name:

```
public static String normaliseTagName(String tagName) {
    // Return a given empty tag name.
    if (tagName.length() == 0) {
        return tagName;
    }

    // Replace invalid start.
    if (isInvalidXMLStart(tagName.charAt(0))) {
        tagName = XML_REPLACEMENT + tagName;
    }

    // Replace invalid characters.
    StringBuilder normalised;
    boolean invalidFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < tagName.length(); i++) {
        if (isInvalidXMLChar(tagName.charAt(i))) {
            if (!invalidFound) {
                normalised = new StringBuilder(tagName.substring(0, i));
                invalidFound = true;
            }
            normalised.append(XML_REPLACEMENT); // COMPILER ERROR
        } else if (invalidFound) {
            normalised.append(tagName.charAt(i)); // COMPILER ERROR
        }
    }

    return invalidFound ? normalised.toString() : tagName; // COMPILER ERROR
}
```

I don't want to initialise the `StringBuilder normalised` before I'm sure to use it. In other words, I want to only initialise it when an invalid XML character is found.

I get `The local variable normalised may not have been initialized` errors where indicated, and I'm puzzled as to why the compiler is telling me that when `normalised` is clearly never used uninitialised.

1. Am I missing something or is the compiler unable to determine the initialisation path of the `StringBuilder normalised` in this situation?
2. If this compilation error cannot be avoided, how can I modify this code so that I initialise the `StringBuilder` only when I need it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use uninitialized local variables. at least you have set it `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly initialize your local variable:

```
StringBuilder normalised = null;
```

... or ...

```
StringBuilder normalised = new StringBuilder();
```

... before referencing it.

Some of the pathways in your code reference `normalised` prior to its initialization:

```
normalised.append(...
```

Local variables are not automatically initialized as would, instance fields.

Comment: `Local variables are not automatically initialized as would, instance fields.` I was not aware of that! So if I use `StringBuilder normalised = null;`, I would be initialising the pointer to null without actually creating anything into memory (which is what I want), is that correct?

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc it will initialize the reference with a `null` value. So it does create **something** in the memory (stack) :) But yes, this is what you want.

Comment: I get it. I assumed local variables had the same initialisation behaviour as instance fields. I learned something today, thanks! :)